# ASP.Net MVC3 - Is there a way to ignore a request?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tcp

I have an ASP MVC3 website with a rest API service.
When a user passes in an invalid API or they have been blacklisted i wish to ignore the response. 
I know I could send back a 404 or pass back an 503 but if someone keeps polling me then I would ideally like to ignore the response causing a time-out their end. Thus delaying the hammering my server gets.

Is this possible within ASP.net MVC3? If so any help would be most appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean ignore the **request** or not **return a response**.

Comment: I meant the latter. Not send a response back. Ideally with the least amount of processing time/burden on the server end.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want, you still need to parse the request, so it will always consume server resources, specially if you have an *annoying user* sending a query every 500ms...

In this situations you would block the IP / Header of the request for a period of, for example 10 minutes, but it would be a very good idea to block it on your load balancer and prevent that request that even reach your application, this is easily accomplish if you're using Amazon Services to run your Service, but all other cloud provider do support this as well, if by any means you are using a cloud hosting.

if you can only use your web application, and this is a solution that is not tested, you could add an ignored route to your routing mechanism like:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allignore}", new {allignore=@".*\.ignore(/.*)?"});
```

and upon check that the IP is banned, simple redirect using for example `Response.Redirect()` to your site, to a `.ignore` path... or, why not redirecting that request to `google.com` just for the fun of it?

Comment: I'm using Azure to host it. Not sure i have access currently to the load balancer. Is this not similar to redirecting to a 404? Except it will happen quicker for the client?

Comment: in Azure you have access to the entire API through REST calls, give it a read on Windows Azure Traffic Manager as that's their layer to handle the requests... you could probably and easily add blocked IP's to it and stop having them querying your application.